# Hide all pages header except the home page

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and a theme.
I want to hide all pages and post header.
So I add

```
.page-header {
    display:none;
}
```

to the css file.

It works. But I dont want to hide the home page header.
How to do that?

Comment: `body:not(.home) .page-header { display: none; }`

Comment: @HashemQolami: thanks. it works! Please make it as an answer and i will mark it.

Comment: It depends on your theme. `home` class name is added to the body by WordPress functions if the theme is taking advantage of. Please check the HTML output to see if body has that class name, if so check the devtools on your browser to see if another selector is overriding that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a function called `body_class()` which gives back some classes depending on the current page (and ...) that can be added to the body element.

> [Function Reference/body class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class)
>
> Themes have a template tag for the body tag which will help theme authors to style more effectively with CSS. The Template Tag is called body_class. This function gives the body element different classes and can be added, typically, in the header.php's HTML body tag.

#### Usage

```php
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

If your theme is making use of that function, you can exclude the homepage from the selector as follows:

```css
body:not(.home) .page-header { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add css to your home page `body` and set it to block

```
.homeapge.page-header {
    display:block;
}
```

### Home page

```
 <body class="... homepage">...</body>
```

Now sinne you have this on your body of the home page it will be visible